How can ChatGPT correctly answer questions containing things that it surely never saw?
I read the paper Attention Is All You Need, and understood the architecture. Searching the Internet, there is a consensus that ChatGPT is (just) a super-sophisticated auto-complete engine, thanks to Large Language Model (LLM). That said, it doesn't truly understand questions like humans [2], [3].
When it seems to not know a thing because the thing was not in the training data, it will try to spit out something anyway [1], leading to so-called hallucination.
I tested it with a term that I'm sure never appeared on the Internet ever. And it managed to answer correctly. In the example below, I believe that the 1st term "ABCDEF" probably existed somewhere in the Internet, e.g. in Computer Science 101 class note/lecture; but the 2nd term is my randomly typed text.
                 

How could ChatGPT "match/generate" the answer for the 2nd example correctly? It can't just match the most probable document somewhere.

Can I safely assume that before feeding into LLM engine, ChatGPT service parses the question first, to see if it is a low-hanging fruit question, e.g. "what is today?", "what's the weather like today?", "when is the flight XYZ from A to B?". Exactly like Google/Bing is already doing. If so, the parser diverts the question (or part of the question) to another specifically designed engine, e.g. HashCalculatorEngine?


References
[1] How does an AI like ChatGPT answer a question in a subject which it may not know?
[2] How does OPENAIs ChatGPT seem to “understand” things
[3] https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=34123186

ChatGPT is running a Python program to compute the SHA-256 hash value. If you click on [>_], you'll see the code it used.
In my case, it is using the following program:
import hashlib

# Text to hash
text = "ABCD"

# Calculate SHA-256 hash
hash_value = hashlib.sha256(text.encode()).hexdigest()
hash_value


Whoever downvoted cares to explain why?

you need to learn how chatgpt prompt engineering works learn here is it one the best courses to learn chatgpt prompt engineering https://www.udemy.com/course/master-chatgpt-prompt-engineering/

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
